# generates hierarchical numbers using xsl:number

Tags: xslt-2.0

consider the following XML document:

```
<alphabets>
    <A>
        <C>
            <E/>
            <F>
                <G/>
                <H/>
            </F>
        </C>
        <D/>
    </A>
    <B>
       <I/> 
    </B>
</alphabets>
```

I want to generate a hierarchical numbers using xsl:number as shown below:

```
1.A
 1.1.C 
  1.1.1.E
  1.1.2.F 
   1.1.2.1.G
   1.1.2.2.H
 1.2.D
2.B
 2.1.I
```

I have tried the following program but unfortunately it doesn't give me what i want as an output:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:template match="alphabets">
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <ul>
                <p>
                    <xsl:number format="1." count="*"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
                    
                </p>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </ul>
        </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <ul>
            <p>
                <xsl:number count="*" format="1.1." level="multiple"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </p>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I hope i have explained clearly my problem.

Comment: 1. Please select either XSLT 1.0 or 2.0, not both. 2. Please edit your question and add the exact expected result **as HTML code**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <xsl:template match="/*//*">
    <xsl:number level="multiple" from="/*/*" count="*" format="1.1"/>
    <xsl:text> {local-name()}&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>
```

in XSLT 3 gives

```
1 A
1.1 C
1.1.1 E
1.1.2 F
1.1.2.1 G
1.1.2.2 H
1.2 D
2 B
2.1 I
```

I would need to check whether all attributes used were also supported in XSLT 2; according to https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#number `from`, `count`, `level`, `format` are all supported in XSLT 2, so above `xsl:number` should hopefully work with an XSLT 2 processor as well. You would need to use `xsl:value-of select="local-name()"` instead of the used text value template I used above, if you are really restricted to an XSLT 2 implementation.

Comment: IIRC the only substantive change to xsl:number in 3.0 was the addition of the start-at attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to produce a hierarchical list of the XML elements, then you should transform each element to a `li` instead of a `p`.

Here is an example using XSLT 1.0:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/alphabets">
    <html>    
        <body>
            <ul>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
            </ul>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
  
<xsl:template match="*">
    <li>
        <xsl:number count="*" from="/*" format="1.1." level="multiple"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
        </ul>
    </li>
</xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will return an HTML document:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <ul>
         <li>1.A
            <ul>
               <li>1.1.C
                  <ul>
                     <li>1.1.1.E
                        <ul></ul>
                     </li>
                     <li>1.1.2.F
                        <ul>
                           <li>1.1.2.1.G
                              <ul></ul>
                           </li>
                           <li>1.1.2.2.H
                              <ul></ul>
                           </li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
               <li>1.2.D
                  <ul></ul>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li>2.B
            <ul>
               <li>2.1.I
                  <ul></ul>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </body>
</html>
```

which in a browser will look like:

[image]